# Reusable object v state and new object creation

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

What are the implications of

```
// Use a setData method to populate data on the object.  This will allow data to be set multiple times with a single object
class Testy
{
    private $data = [];

    public function setData(array $data)
    {
       $this->data = $data;      
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        foreach($this->data as $data) {
            if (! isset($data['id'])) {
                return false;   
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

versus

```
// Set data using the constructor that will require multiple objects to handle multiple use cases
class Testy
{
    private $data = [];

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
       $this->data = $data;      
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        foreach($this->data as $data) {
            if (! isset($data['id'])) {
                return false;   
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

versus

```
// Set data to be validated directly on the validate method.  This is the most concise of the 3 but the class simply becomes a wrapper for the method which may be a smell that it belongs elsewhere.
class Testy
{
    public function validate($data)
    {
        foreach($data as $data) {
            if (! isset($data['id'])) {
                return false;   
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

To provide some context: the example is very simplified and each $data array will contain objects used for validation.  I wanted to know in a scenario where this object might be used several times in a given request, which of the examples would be considered better and if there are any implications of any of the approaches listed.

Comment: Though it will be pretty clear to many readers after studying it for a moment, could you add some comments as to the differences and the purpose of the differences - like "pass $data to constructor & store", "pass data to setter" etc...

Comment: No expert, but in the first example and the third example you can create an invalid `Testy` object and then have the ability to potentially perform invalid operations on it. By placing the `$data` in the constructor you ensure that for the life cycle of the object you *should* have a valid object to work with and all your methods should work. There was a really good blog post about the life cycle of PHP objects somewhere, i'll see if I can hunt it down -- again I'm not expert so take what I say with a pinch of salt :p

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i updated with explenations

Comment: For the implication of setters vs. constructors (1 vs. 2) search for pros and cons of **immutability**. For the implication of objects vs. utilities (1&2 vs. 3) search for pros and cons of **object-oriented programming**.